# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error when trying to save XML into file

Tags: xml, database, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to save XMLTYPE data that created using function GENERATE_XML_FROM_TABLE into file. When I try to save little number of characters it's all working. But for bigger sizes it's causes error " numeric or value error when trying to save XML into file".

```
    PROCEDURE SAVE_XML_TO_FILE (TARGET_TABLE VARCHAR2)
IS
   FILE_TO_SAVE   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   XMLCLOB        CLOB;
BEGIN
   XMLCLOB := GENERATE_XML_FROM_TABLE (TARGET_TABLE).GETCLOBVAL ();
   FILE_TO_SAVE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('DATA', 'CLASSIF.xml', 'W');
   UTL_FILE.PUT (FILE_TO_SAVE, XMLCLOB);
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (FILE_TO_SAVE);
END;
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using, and which line throws the exception? Including the whole exception stack in the question might be useful.

Comment: Using ORACLE 10g, This line throws exception:  UTL_FILE.PUT (FILE_TO_SAVE, XMLCLOB).   Full stack: [Error] Execution (1: 3): ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SAVE_XML_TO_FILE ", line 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size of the buffer for [`put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_FILE.html#GUID-B2AA62D6-2CF8-43E2-AE64-73939F1545AD) is 32767, unless a smaller size is specified in `fopen()`; and the default `max_line_size` for [`fopen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_FILE.html#GUID-B2AA62D6-2CF8-43E2-AE64-73939F1545AD) is 1024 characters.

Essentially you need to write the CLOB out in chunks, and you might as well use larger buffers:

```
PROCEDURE SAVE_XML_TO_FILE (TARGET_TABLE VARCHAR2)
IS
   FILE_TO_SAVE   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   XMLCLOB        CLOB;
   POSITION       PLS_INTEGER := 1;
   CHARS          PLS_INTEGER := 32767;
   BUFFER         VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
   XMLCLOB := GENERATE_XML_FROM_TABLE (TARGET_TABLE).GETCLOBVAL ();

   FILE_TO_SAVE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('DATA', 'CLASSIF.xml', 'W', CHARS);

   WHILE POSITION < DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH (XMLCLOB) LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.READ (XMLCLOB, CHARS, POSITION, BUFFER);
      UTL_FILE.PUT (FILE_TO_SAVE, BUFFER);
      UTL_FILE.FFLUSH (FILE_TO_SAVE);
      POSITION := POSITION + CHARS;
   END LOOP;

   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (FILE_TO_SAVE);
END;
/
```

I've added `CHARS` to the ``fopen()` call, so that will be 32767. Then I'm reading the CLOB into the buffer in chunks of up to 32767 characters, and writing and - importantly - flushing each buffer.

You'll still have a problem if the XML in the CLOB has no line breaks, but hopefully it's prettified; if not you can use XMLSerialise to achieve that before writing.

Comment: Thank you for help. Yes, XML has no break lines, so I added  .extract('/*')   at the end of XML generate and now it's all working